# Certificate transparency quickstart : how to monitor a list of domains?

Tags: certificate

### Context :

I'd like to use transparency logs provided by https://www.certificate-transparency.org to monitor certificate issual for bunch of domains.

Yet, I can't find a way to start.

### Question :

Are you aware of a good quickstart / do you have any hints on how to do it ?

### Use case :

Watching for `example.org` in the logs, I'd like to find a way to raise an alarm if something like `login.example.org` is beeing issued (or any subdomains)

### Bonus :

Being able to watch for other RDNs like `O=Example Co. Ltd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has a [client implementation in Python](https://github.com/google/certificate-transparency/tree/master/python). You can use it to monitor the logs, create a database clone, and then routinely search the database for your entries.

Comment: Thanks kichik, I'll give it a try. I'm also trying https://github.com/SSLMate/certspotter